# Sox: Trimming at the end of a mp3 file

Tags: macos, audio, mp3, sox

I'm struggling a bit with sox. I am trying to simply cut off 1.2 seconds of the end of a file. I know there is a `trim` function in sox, but I am not sure how to use it so it cuts off the exact time at the end? I know it works like this roughly:

`sox input output trim <start> <duration>`

However, the only solution I could come up with would be something like this (Pseudocode) :

`sox input output trim <length of whole mp3 file -1.2 seconds> <1.2 seconds>`

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

`sox input output trim 0 -1.2`